# Network connection doesn't work on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on top of Oracle Virtual Box on Windows 10. I couldn't get network connection working.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The wireless adapter doesn't pass through to a VM. You'll only see Ethernet and that's a virtual bridge to the physical adapter.

Comment: Zacharee1 is exactly right.  The Bridged adapter tells the VM what network from the host you are going to use, but the advanced shows the VM what it is creating.  You are seeing in your Ubuntu the Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop virtual adapter.  If you need direct access to a Wifi adapter or Wifi network, I would suggest a USB adapter as the VM will get direct access to a USB device.

Comment: Thanks Zacharee1 and Terrance.  Yes, you are right. I just learnt  there is no wireless connection inside the virtualbox environment. But I still couldn't get my network connectiong working.  I updated my question before I saw your answers.  Could you please advise how I can get my Ethernet connect working? Thanks a lo.t

Comment: Thanks. I finally managed to get it working now. Thanks Zacharee1 and Terrance's input.